# Cakephp 3.5 save same record multiple times

Tags: cakephp, view, controller, cakephp-3.x

maybe this question already exists, but so far I have not been able to find a solution for me.

What I would like to do is the following.

When creating a dataset, next to the "Save" button, I have a selection box with values (5,10,15,20). This should determine how often the same record should be created with the same content. Apart from the ID which should be clear.

Does this work at all and if so how do I implement this in the controller?

This is my code.

**view.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'),['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->select(
        'copies', [
            '1' => '1 time',
            '5' => '5 times',
            '10' => '10 times',
            '15' => '15 times',
            '20' => '20 times'
        ],
        [
            'label' => false,
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ]
    );
?>
<p class="help-block">How often should this record be created?</p>
```

The field "copies" is just a variable of mine. Thus, the copy field does not exist in the database table.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Ello my vriend.
A for loop with a $tableClass->saveMany() method should work for ya

```
//This is the data that comes from ur form
$data = $this->request->data;
//convert to int
$copies = (int)$data['copies'];
//Empty array that will be filled with data
$to_save = [];
//Time to loop!
for($i = 0; $i < $copies; $i++)
  {
    //Push the data into the array
    $to_save[] = $some_data_array_to_be_inserted_that_probably_comes_from_the_request_data;
  }
//Register the tableclass
$somethingTable = TableRegistry::get('Something');
//The saveMany() method of a tableClass works as a wrapper for save() method within a loop
if(!$somethingTable->saveMany($to_save))
  {
     //Error
     echo 'Eita!';
  }
else
  {
     //Success!
  }
```